# Apply hover on outer class but not on inner divs

Tags: javascript, css

```
    <article class="post blog-post" itemprop="blogPost" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemscope="itemscope">

            <div class="one-third first">
            ...
            </div>
            <div class="two-thirds">
            ...
            </div>

    </article>
```

I am trying to implement border styling when hover on **blog-post** using following code, it place border on hover on every single div inside  **blog-post**  class but not on  **blog-post**  class

```
.blog-post :hover {
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

how to place border on hover on .blog-post class?

Comment: Remove the space between .blog-post and :hover in your CSS

Comment: Your CSS currently selects all items with the class `.blog-post` and **all** hovered elements. As @Gerard pointed out: Remove the space.

Comment: Thanks. that solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the pseudo-state directly to the intended target element:

`.blog-post:hover {border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}`

```css
.blog-post:hover {
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<article class="post blog-post" itemprop="blogPost" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemscope="itemscope">

  <div class="one-third first">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="two-thirds">
    ...
  </div>

</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be a possiblity is wrapping the article in a `<div>` and add the hover attributes to that div.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

using direct `article` in css

```css
article:hover {
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<article class="post blog-post" itemprop="blogPost" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting" itemscope="itemscope">
  <div class="one-third first">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="two-thirds">
    ...
  </div>
</article>
```